# How to read java heap remotely for an android application?

Tags: java, android, heap-memory

We have released android application and start receiving reports with memory issues. 
Is it possible to read java heap on a remote device for the application installed from the play store without root access?

Comment: Couldn't you send to the user guidelines on how to produce a heap dump and provide it to you ?

Comment: Let us hope it is not possible

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/profile you should profile your app for memory leaks.

Comment: You may simulate on a virtual device with low memory.

Comment: @nullPointer If posible we would like to do it without user notice.

Comment: @PeterMmm cannot reproduce it on our devices and emulators